# SD Card Reader not recognized

Tags: drivers

I am using elementary OS on Dell latitude 3440, it has an inbuilt SD card reader. Elementary OS does not recognize an SD Card. However the same was working under Windows.

Comment: Please [edit] and add output of `ls /dev/sd*` with and without card reader.

Comment: Also output of `df -h` with and without card reader. And output of `lspci -v`

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to also include `tail dmesg` after inserting a card.

Comment: I see the drive with all of the above. Gparted displays the drive. It just doesn't show up in file manager.

Comment: Please add output to question, @kkites